# Getting unexpected DEM spatial resolution using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, resolution, srtm

I have downloaded SRTM DEM 30 m. However, when I displayed on ArcMap, I got a DEM raster with 0.0002777 cell size.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the CRS of the DEM?

Comment: The coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your DEM seems to be in a geographic CRS ( EPSG:4326 ; WGS84), the unit of measurement is in degrees, not in meters. So measurements of length do not make sense: your cellsize is 0.0002777 degrees.

Reproject your DEM to a projected CRS to have meters as measurement unit.